# hiding source maps on react

Tags: reactjs, templates, material-ui, dashboard

I am working with a minimal dashboard template and would like to push my website to production.

How could I hide the source maps on react?

FYI: using yarn to build

Tried varies guides from the internet, probably it is something really simple but as I am new to developing with react it proves to be more complicated than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP to false in build script.
This is part of package.json.

```
"scripts": {    
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Also, you can create .env file on your root directory and set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false